# I woulld like to change the colour of table cell "td" based on the value i have fetched

Tags: python, html, html-table

I would like to change the colour of table cell "td" based on the value i have fetched.The colour of "td" for value4 should be yellow if value6==0.The table gets appended based on the query results.

code snippet:

```
def result(mytuple):
    print("In Table")
    FULL_HTML = []
    print("in Html")
    for name, rows in groupby(mytuple, itemgetter(0)):
        table = []
        for name, value1, value2, value3, value4,value5,value6, value7 in rows:
            table.append("<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(name, value1, value2, value3, value4,value5))
        table = "{}".format('\n'.join(table))
        print("Appending to table")
            #FULL_HTML.append(table)
        FULL_HTML.append(table)
    FULL_HTML = "{}\n</table>".format("\n".join(FULL_HTML))
    print(FULL_HTML)
    print(type(FULL_HTML))
    return (FULL_HTML)
```

Comment: Do you know how to color an HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change the background color the cell ( html element). As you are handbacking your html, the easiest route is to use the `bgcolor` attribute, like this :

```
<td bgcolor="yellow">
```

This is old school, but will work. Better would be to use the style attribute with a little bit of css inside :

```
<td style="background-color:yellow">
```

Then to choose the color :

```
 for name, value1, value2, value3, value4,value5,value6, value7 in rows:
            color = "white"
            if value6 == 0 :
                 color = "yellow"
            table.append("<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td bgcolor='{}'>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(name, value1, value2, value3, color, value4,value5))
```

Note :

Your `table = "{}".format('\n'.join(table))` is weird, `table = '\n'.join(table)` should be enough... same for `FULL_HTML = "{}\n</table>".format("\n".join(FULL_HTML))`, `FULL_HTML = "<table>"+"\n".join(FULL_HTML)) + "\n</table>` should do the trick (you also miss the start tag).